# Separating even and odd numbers

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a file with the first 100 numbers and I have to take only the even numbers to another file. How can I do this with `grep`?

Comment: Are the numbers newline separated?

Comment: First of all, what have you tried so far ?  Second, this is basically continuation of your previous question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/891106/filling-a-file-with-odd-and-even-numbers-novice-stuff). How does it differ ? Why have you not requested to reopen the question in the comments instead of posting new one ?

Comment: @Serg I would say it differs in that the other question is too broad and this one is not. Yes better to edit the other one, but new users aren't always aware of what we consider best practice :)

Comment: Google is [your friend](https://gist.github.com/bashyal/9145373) First hit when I query grep for even numbers....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the numbers are newline separated, with `awk`:

```
awk '! ($0 % 2)' file.txt
```

To save the output in a file:

```
awk '! ($0 % 2) {print >"even.txt"}' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt             
1
2
3
4

% awk '! ($0 % 2)' file.txt
2
4

% awk '! ($0 % 2) {print >"even.txt"}' file.txt 

% cat even.txt 
2
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex with `grep`

```
grep "^[0-9]*[13579]$" FILE > oddsfile.txt

grep "^[0-9]*[02468]$" FILE > evensfile.txt
```

This pipes the file into the grep, which matches to the regex and writes it to a file

Comment: First of all, your command is wrong. This will take out only 1,3,5,7,9 to file.  odd numbers from 0 to 100 include more than that. Second, you are using useless `cat`; instead `grep` can take file as argument.

Comment: ^\d*[13579]$ means Start, 0 or more digits, one of 1 3 5 7 9, end. It will only match numbers ending in odd digits, which are odd numbers. Same for evens

Comment: Have you tested it yourself ? See http://paste.ubuntu.com/24150036/

Comment: Hmm. Try cat FILE | grep "^\[0-9]*[13579]$" > oddsfile.txt

Comment: good, that works. Also, the error in previous command was that you need `-P` for perl-style regex

Comment: Edit  your post so that I can remove the downvote. Otherwise the system won't let me

Comment: Done. And thanks for the -P I'm sure that will turn out to be useful.

Comment: UUOC: Just do `grep ... FILE` instead of `cat FILE | grep ...`

Comment: @muru already mentioned in the first comment

Comment: @Serg OP seems to have missed it, focusing on the more important regex problem

Comment: My original solution seemed simpler, cutting the steps apart instead of bunching them all together because anmapaf seemed like a newer user given the simple nature of the question (easily googleable), but I do like the more elegant solution as well

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are space-separated (all on one line), test this:

```
grep -E '(^| )1?[0-9]?[02468]( |$)' file
```

Got it!

Add the `-o` switch for match-only and redirect to a new file:

```
grep -Eo '(^| )1?[0-9]?[02468]( |$)' file > newfile
```

If the numbers are newline separated:

```
grep -E '^1?[0-9]?[02468]$' file > newfile
```

#### Notes:

- `-E` use extended regular expressions
- `(this|that)` match `this` or `that`
- `^` start of line
- `$` end of line
- `?` zero or one of the preceding character